# DataGridTemplateColumn using ContentPresenter in HeaderStyle

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn, contentpresenter

I am using couple of `DataGridTemplateColumn`s in my XAML `DataGrid`, each one of which is group of text boxes, since I wanted a grouped header layout for the columns (e.g. merged columns as headers in excel).

All of this works fine, since I am using the `HeaderStyle` property of the column to load a `StaticResource` for `Style` that defines a `Grid` layout and implements the grouped headers.

The issue is, the `Header` property of the `DataGridTemplateColumn` needs to be bound to a model member (or a StaticResource ?), since that will contain a string value that will be used in a `ContentPresenter`, which is part of the `HeaderStyle`. The `ContentPresenter` in the `Style` resource is defined as follows:

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
Grid.ColumnSpan="11">
```

But this doesn't work. It only works if `Header="SomeString`, but as soon as I change it to
`Header="{Binding Something}"` or `Header="{StaticResource SomeResource}"` it just shows a blank header.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score -1):

Remove Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" as this is incorrect. The ContentPresenter will implicitly use the content supplied to it as part of the template

Comment: I see, though that isn't solving the problem. To be precise, the `DataGridTemplateColumn` is defined as follows     `<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Something}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource SomeHeaderStyle}"
    CellTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}"/>`